# In Intellij IDEA 15, how do I exclude certain items from optimize imports?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I typically want IntelliJ IDEA always optimize imports and never use wildcards.  However, in test classes, I never want static imports for the following entries to be optimized, or even removed even if they're not in use:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify excluding rules for appropriate Java packages in IntellijIdea Settings.

Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Code Style** -> **Java**. Now you may see: 
[image]

Then you need to click to tab **"Imports"**. To apply exclusion rules please add packages to "Packages to Use Import with '*'". I added exclusion for `org.junit.*` and for `org.mockito.*`: 
[image: Add packages]

Now you need to save this configuration and even if you go to you test class and run "Optimize imports" it won't do anything with static imports you specified.